# JQuery return 401 Unauthorized from REST service

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, heroku

I'm working on small sound app for my facultity, its on https://portfolio-st.herokuapp.com

My problem jquery function for songs request return me status 401 but when i call rest api controller directly https://portfolio-st.herokuapp.com/api/songs , it working fine.

AJAX call:

```
getPlaylist : function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : basePath + '/songs',
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        success : function(songs) {
            $('#radioPlaylist').empty();
            for (let song of songs) {
                $('#radioPlaylist').append(
                '<div class="form-group">' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control songText" value="#'+ song.id + ' '+ song.title + '" disabled="disabled">' +
                '</div>');
            }
        }
    });     
},
```

I'm using ClearDB addon for mysql database and my MySQL Workbench desktop app working.

```
Response headers (431 B)    
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:at, 09 Mar 2019 16:07:20 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Cowboy
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Via :1.1 vegur
X-Content-Type-Options  :nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block

Request headers (409 B) 
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding :gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host:portfolio-st.herokuapp.com
Referer:https://portfolio-st.herokuapp.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Just use a different ‘cobtentType’. Remove that line and it will work.

Comment: @muecas I did it and still same.

Comment: can you open the debugger and check the sent and returned headers for the request? Can you add them to the question?

Comment: @muecas On local machine it works, but when i deploy i get that error.

Comment: the app must have some auto method. Please check in the deployed version the console for the request and add to your question the sent and returned headers.

Comment: @muecas question updated.